# Use Dojo to load modularized widget config files

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I've taken a basic webmap '[ESRI HomeButton](http://esri.github.io/arcgis-dijit-home-button-js/)' and I'm trying to create a modularized webmap setup from it. I want to break down this simple webmap to have it utilizing a module system with config files and more. Then I can take other single-use webmaps and breakout the widgets into separate files much more easily and approach everything very much like the FlexViewer environment.

The problem I am having is that in my widgetHomeButton.js file, I took the HomeButton.js code and added in three lines...

In my require, I added "widgets/homebutton/config" to point to my config.js file. I should mention I have a package.js file that sets up the folders so that 'widgets' points to package_path + "path/to/widgets" just like in the example.

In my function, I added **widgetConfig** as the variable to store the config.js file contents, which happen to be JSON style data.

Then in the HomeButton widget code I added a single line of code that reads...

```
console.log( widgetConfig );
```

And all I get are errors. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, Use dojo/text! and JSON.parse to grab config:

Assumes directory structure something like:

```
/src/js/MyWidget
  - /templates
    - MyWidget.html
  - MyWidget.js
  - MyWidgetConfig.js
```

MyWidget.js:

```
// Define Widget Module
define(
  [
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/text!./templates/MyWidget.html",
    "dojo/text!./MyWidgetConfig.js",
  ],
  function (declare, domConstruct, template, widgetConfigJson) {
    'use strict'; // ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode

    return declare(null, {
        constructor: function (map, srcNodeRef) {
          this.map = map;

          // place templated html
          domConstruct.place(template, srcNodeRef);

          // parse json config into object.
          // name file .js instead of .json
          var widgetConfig = JSON.parse(widgetConfigJson);
        });
    });
});
```